# upload image file to different server

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I want to upload image on different server. Image is being uploaded. but it's not in correct format.
For this code it works file.

**SAME SERVER (WORKING)**

```
$file_path = "./media/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

**ANOTHER SERVER (WORKING BUT NOT GETTING ACTUAL IMAGE)**

```
$file_name = $cus_id . ".jpg";
$file_path = CUS_PROFILE_PIC_DOCROOT . $file_name;

$ftp_server = "some_address";
$ftp_user = "username";
$ftp_password = "password";
$conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die ("Cannot connect to host");
if (@ftp_login($conn, $ftp_user, $ftp_password)) {
    ftp_pasv($conn, true);
    $uploaded = ftp_put($conn, $file_path, $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], FTP_ASCII);
    ftp_close($conn);
    if($uploaded){
        echo "success";
    }
    else{
        echo "fail";
    }
} else {
    return "Couldn't connect as $ftp_user\n";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I am getting image. But, not in it's actual format. image is like 950 kb. but everytime I can see 60 kb. and it's not supported by windows image viewer.

Comment: convert to base64 or binary

Comment: Did you try using FTP_BINARY instead of FTP_ASCII?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois : ohh. It's working with `FTP_BINARY`. Thank you so much. I don't know what's the reason behind that though.

Comment: @RonakPatel: You were sending an image (which is a binary format) as ASCII.  FTP probably interpreted one of the binary bits as a command or EOF or something.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois you should answer this question, so it can be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use FTP_BINARY for images since they're binary. You should only send textfiles as ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code to upload :

```
//  set_time_limit(0);
        $connection = ftp_connect("domain.com");
        $login = ftp_login($connection, "admin", "pass");
        if (!$connection)
            {
             die('Connection attempt failed!');
            }
        else{
             echo "connection passed";
             }
    if (!$login)
            {
             die('Login attempt failed!');
            }
            else{
            echo "login passed";
            }
    ftp_pasv($connection, true);

<p>    $source = "image.jpg";
    $dest = "folder/image.jpg";</p>
<p>    //$x = substr($dest,-4);
    // echo $x;</p>
<p>    if((substr($dest,-4) == ".jpg") || (substr($dest,-4) == ".png") )
{
 //no problems;
}
else {
die('only jpg or png.');
}</p>
<p>    $upload = ftp_put($connection, $dest, $source, FTP_BINARY);
    if (!$upload) { echo 'FTP upload failed!'; } else {echo "ftp upload passed";}</p>
<p>    ftp_close($connection);</p>
<p>?></p>
```